# GPUImage Lookup Filter - creating a color depth greater than 512² colors

Tags: ios, macos, opengl-es, gpuimage

GPUImage's LookupFilter uses an RGB pixel map that's 512x512. When the filter executes, it creates a comparison between a modified version of this image with the original, and extrapolates an image filter.

[image]

The filter code is pretty straightforward. Here's an extract so you can see what's going on:

```
void main()
 {
     highp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);

     highp float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0;

     highp vec2 quad1;
     quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);
     quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);

     highp vec2 quad2;
     quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 8.0);
     quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);

     highp vec2 texPos1;
     texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
     texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

     highp vec2 texPos2;
     texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);
     texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);

     lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);
     lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);

     lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, fract(blueColor));
     gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w), intensity);
 }
);
```

See where the filter map is dependent on this being a 512x512 image?

I'm looking at ways to 4x the color depth here, using a 1024x1024 source image instead, but I'm not sure how this lookup filter image would have originally been generated.

**Can something like this be generated in code?** If so, I realize it's a very broad question, but how would I go about doing that? If it can't be generated in code, what are my options?

—-

**Update:**

Turns out the original LUT generation code was included in the header file all along. The questionable part here is from the header file:

> Lookup texture is organised as 8x8 quads of 64x64 pixels representing all possible RGB colors:

How is 64x64 a map of all possible RGB channels? 64³ = 262,144 but that only accounts for 1/64th of the presumed 24-bit capacity of RGB, which is 64³ (16,777,216). What's going on here? Am I missing the way this LUT works? How are we accounting for all possible RGB colors with only 1/64th of the data?

```
for (int by = 0; by < 8; by++) {
   for (int bx = 0; bx < 8; bx++) {
       for (int g = 0; g < 64; g++) {
           for (int r = 0; r < 64; r++) {
               image.setPixel(r + bx * 64, g + by * 64, qRgb((int)(r * 255.0 / 63.0 + 0.5),
                                                             (int)(g * 255.0 / 63.0 + 0.5),
                                                             (int)((bx + by * 8.0) * 255.0 / 63.0 + 0.5)));
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what problem you are actually having. When you say you want "4x the color depth" what do you actually mean. Color depth normally means the number of bits per color channel (or per pixel), which is totally independent of the resolution of the image.

In terms of lookup table accuracy (which is resolution dependent), assuming you are using bilinear filtered texture inputs from the original texture, and filtered lookups into the transform table, then you are already linearly interpolating between samples in the lookup table. Interpolation of color channels will be at higher precision than the storage format; e.g. often fp16 equivalent, even for textures stored at 8-bit per pixel.

Unless you have a significant amount of non-linearity in your color transform (not that common) adding more samples to the lookup table is unlikely to make a significant difference to the output - the interpolation will already be doing a reasonably good job of filling in the gaps.

Comment: Ultimately I think this does make sense - the practicality of using a 1024x1024 pixel lookup table may not visually make much difference here. What I'm mostly interested in is how to _generate_ such a lookup table in the first place. Can it be easily done with code? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: How to do it will depend on what color transform are you looking to apply; in most cases there is some idealized maths equation which encodes the tone mapping, so it's just a case of iterating though that in the three axes you care about.

Answer (score 1):

Lev Zelensky [provided the original work for this](http://liovch.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/add-instagram-like-effects-to-your-ios.html), so I'm not as familiar with how this works internally, but you can look at the math being performed in the shader to get an idea of what's going on.

In the 512x512 lookup, you have an 8x8 grid of cells. Within those cells, you have a 64x64 image patch. The red values go from 0 to 255 (0.0 to 1.0 in normalized values) going from left to right in that patch, and the green values go from 0 to 255 going down. That means that there are 64 steps in red, and 64 steps in green.

Each cell then appears to increase the blue value as you progress down the patches, left to right, top to bottom. With 64 patches, that gives you 64 blue values to match the 64 red and green ones. That gives you equal coverage across the RGB values in all channels.

So, if you wanted to double the number of color steps, you'd have to double the patch size to 128x128 and have 128 grids. It'd have to be more of a rectangle due to 128 not having an integer square root. Just going to 1024x1024 might let you double the color depth in the red and green channels, but blue would now be half their depth. Balancing the three out would be a little trickier than just doubling the image size.

Comment:  thanks for the thoughtful reply Brad. Much work I have to do.